# HTML Table Get Fixed Table Header for more then 20 row

Tags: jquery, html, css

would like to be able to "tweak" an HTML table's presentation to add a single feature: when scrolling down through the page so that the table is on the screen but the header rows are off-screen, I would like the headers to remain visible at the top of the viewing area for table more then 20 rows.

This would be conceptually like the "freeze panes" feature in Excel. However, an HTML page might contain several tables in it and I only would want it to happen for the table that is currently in-view, only while it is in-view.

Comment: Examples: [Example 1](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu),[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this jQuery plugin: http://www.fixedheadertable.com

With it you can fix the header of the table you want.

Comment: Could you add an example of using the plugin?